# a function that evaluates a Section

Tags: function-construction, argument-patterns

I have defined a function that returns different output according to the values of the axes of an ellipsoidal. The function is given below:

```
S[α1_, α2_, α3_, v_] := 
 Module[{sortedargs}, 
  sortedargs = SortBy[-# &][{α1, α2, α3}];
  Print["Ellipsoidal axes ", " a1: ", α1, ", a2: ", α2, 
   ", a3: ", α3]; 
  Which[(*sphere*)α1 == α2 == α3, 
   Print["spherical inclusion"]; 
   SMat = SSphere[α1, α2, α3, v]; 
   Return[SMat],(*prolate spheroid*)(sortedargs[[2]] == 
      sortedargs[[3]] && α3/α1 <= 1000), 
   Print["Prolate Spheroidal Inclusion"]; 
   SMat = SProlateSpheroid[α1, α2, α3, v]; 
   Return[SMat],(*oblate spheroid*)sortedargs[[1]] == sortedargs[[2]],
    Print["Oblate Spheroidal Inclusion"]; 
   SMat = SOblateSpheroid[α1, α2, α3, v]; 
   Return[SMat], α3/α1 > 1000, 
   Print["cylindrical inclusion"]; 
   SMat = SCylinder[α1, α2, α3, v]; 
   Return[SMat],(*generic ellipsoid spheroid*)True, 
   Print["generic ellipsoid"]; 
   SMat = SEllipsoidGen[α1, α2, α3, v]; 
   Return[SMat]]]
```

What I want is if none of the [`Which`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Which.html) statement cases is not satisfied then the function will evaluate the contents of a whole section within the same notebook (that actually contains several numerical integrations) and return as `SMat` the final output of this section.

How is it possible to do this?

Thank you very much!

PS.
For the sake of completeness I provide the link with the original discussion about this function.

[link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84647/construct-a-function-whose-definition-depends-on-the-values-of-its-arguments/84734#84734)

Comment: You can put that whole section into a `Module`, assign a name to it, like `runSection := Module[{}, ...]`, and then add a last case to `Which` in the form of `True, runSection`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To evaluate the contents of a whole section within the same notebook and return its output please use the following simple function (which should be placed within the section you want to be evaluated)

```
EvalSection := Block[{notebook, nb, thissection, result}, 
 "find me 31415"; notebook = NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]]; 
  thissection = Select[Cases[notebook, CellGroupData[a__], Infinity], 
       ! FreeQ[#1, "\"find me 31415\""] & ]; 
  nb = CreateDocument[]; 
  NotebookWrite[nb, thissection]; 
  result = NotebookEvaluate[nb,InsertResults -> True]; 
  NotebookClose[nb]; result]
```

To test it please run EvalSection outside the section to avoid obvious infinite loops. Enjoy!