# I want to run 5 different simulation cases over an entire Mathematica Workbook?

Tags: notebooks, infinite-loop

I want to loop over the case numbers, so run cases 1 -5 without manually changing.

caseNumber = 1;

Which[caseNumber == 1, dataString = "Jan", caseNumber == 2,
   dataString = "Feb", caseNumber == 3, 
  dataString = "March", caseNumber == 4, 
  dataString = "April", caseNumber == 5, 
  dataString = "May"  ];

I then want to run the whole mathematica notebook for the first case, then return to the start of the notebook to run the next case, etc. The notebook is contained in a single section with hundreds of cells.

The notebook ends with
writeYourCSV[dataString<>"MathematicaData.csv", TableOfValues];

I don't need to view any of the output in mathamatica, I only need the outputted csv file. So if I could get the loop I would end up with 5 csv files.

Comment: do not think in terms of "notebooks", think in terms of functions. Make a function and call it using arguments.  Notebook is not a function.

Comment: I used to write code like this.  Every time I wanted to change something, I quit the kernel, change the value of the one variable at the beginning of the notebook, and then run all the contents of this notebook, with the result being printed at the end.  Since then I have evolved.  Consider condensing everything into a single function.  Use scoping constructs like `Module` to help.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  Since my code is hundred of lines long that would be a very long function.    In this link a whole section is evaluated.  How would I do this and loop over:   http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94213/a-function-that-evaluates-a-section

Answer (score 1):

First set the caseNumber to be 0, will loop the following code:

```
If[Head[caseNumber] === Symbol, caseNumber = 0;]

caseNumber += 1;

Pause[0.5];

Print["Current Iteration: ", caseNumber]

Which[caseNumber == 1, dataString = "Jan", caseNumber == 2, 
dataString = "Feb", caseNumber == 3, dataString = "March", caseNumber == 4, 
dataString = "April", caseNumber == 5, dataString = "May"];
```

(* Any code you want to put in the loop*)

```
export[caseNumber] = 
Export["File#" <> ToString[caseNumber] <> ".txt", dataString];
```

*** All code above will be looped.

Here use the If control to avoid further output:

```
If[caseNumber < 5, NotebookEvaluate@EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

Current Iteration: 2

Current Iteration: 3

Current Iteration: 4

Current Iteration: 5

```
Clear[caseNumber]
```

Then there will be 5 files under the default directory, which can be obtained by evaluating Directory[]

```
Directory[]
```